# How can I have Spring integration channel dispatch to Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I am new to kafka and tried to create a Spring boot app that takes a rest request and posts it to Kafka Queue. I posted the code snippets as I have. The request is received and then sent to the `testlogchannel`. I was anticipating based on the configuration that I have a JSON that will be posted to Kafka topic. I have a process consuming the messages using the command `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic testlog --from-beginning`. I notice that the messages never go to Kafka topic but are ending up in a test binder of type `TestSupportBinder`. Surprisingly the kafka binder is never used even though I have configuration setup in `application.yml` and `pom.xml`. I use `Java`/`Annotation` based configuration and do not use xml.

*Can someone point to what I am missing here? How can I have the channel dispatch messages to kafka and use kafka binder?*

My **application.yml** snippet is as below

```
spring:
    cloud:
        stream:
            default-binder: kafka
            kafka:
                binder:
                    brokers: localhost
                    zk-nodes: localhost
                bindings:
                    testlogchannel:
                        destination: testlog
```

Producer Channel class:

```
public interface TestLogProducerChannel{

    @Output("testlogchannel")
    MessageChannel testLogWrite();
}
```

Message sending component:

```
@Component
public class MessageProducerUtil {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageProducerUtil.class);

    private final MessageChannel consumer;

    public MessageProducerUtil(TestLogProducerChannel channel) {
        this.consumer = channel.testLogWrite();
    }

    public void sendMessage(TestLog log) {
        Message<TestLog> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(log).build();
        LOG.debug("Sending log object" + log);
        this.consumer.send(msg);
    }

}
```

My maven dependencies are as under:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-loader-tools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Kafka support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My Rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/app/v1.0")
public class TestLogResource {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestLogResource.class);

    @Autowired
    private MessageProducerUtil producer;
    @PostMapping("testlog")
    public ResponseEntity<TestLog> postTestLog(@RequestBody(required = true) TestLog testLog) {
        producer.sendMessage(testLog);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(testLog, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to add the `java` tag instead of the `javascript` tag?

Comment: Once I removed `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` from maven dependencies, I found that the `kafka` binder is now used. I did want to use `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` for testing. Is there any way I can force spring to use Kafka binder instead of test binder by including the `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` in `pom.xml`.