# Spring integration message channel not posting message on kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream which uses Spring Boot for configuration, utilizing MessageChannel I'm trying to post some messages to the channel which are getting sent and received.
I have also specified a destination for that channel which is a Kafka topic(for which the args/ binder properties I've already set in the application.properties file), somehow still
I'm not able to receive any message on my consumer console, apparently there seems to be nothing suspicious visible in the logs as well. (The kafka topic is already created)

This is been shown in my logs:

```
2017-06-26 17:41:08.305 DEBUG 8520 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'output', message: GenericMessage [payload={ "name": "ABC", "emailAddress":"abc@gmail.com","password":"xxx"}, headers={kafka_topic=new-topic, id=8dbc3fba-c30c-ea43-e269-7b5a24d6d8e7, timestamp=1498479068305}]
2017-06-26 17:41:08.305 DEBUG 8520 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'output', message: GenericMessage [payload={ "name": "ABC", "emailAddress":"abc@gmail.com","password":"xxx"}, headers={kafka_topic=new-topic, id=8dbc3fba-c30c-ea43-e269-7b5a24d6d8e7, timestamp=1498479068305}]
2017-06-26 17:41:08.305  INFO 8520 --- [           main] c.f.e.c.stream.MyApplication: ****************In MyApplication, sent = :true
```

application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=new-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=new-topic
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.defaultBrokerPort=9092
```

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication {

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyApplication.class);

@Autowired
private Source source;

public void sendMessage(String json) {
logger.info("In MyApplication, sent = :"+ source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(json).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "new-topic").build()));
  }
}
```

P.S.: Works if I use Kafka producer console to send messages which are consumed by the consumer, also I tried the same programmatically using Kafka Producer.

I'd really appreciate if anyone could help me out in knowing what is not making it work or if anything is missing from the above setup. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to send without `setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "new-topic")` - the bidner should do that for your. Plus you can switch of `async` nature of `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` and maybe see some exception: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_kafka_producer_properties

Comment: @ArtemBilan I did the above, it still didn't work. However what made it work was removing "spring-cloud-stream-test-support" from my maven dependencies which is a temporary fix, but I want that to be working even with the said dependency included. Courtesy: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43127239/1004631

Comment: Well, sounds like `TestBinder` has a priority above any other. Anyway, pay attention to the `<scope>test` for that `scs-test-support`. That way it won't be packaged into application for production.